# If $A$ is a connected set, then its closure $A'$ is connected.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

If $A$ is a connected set, then its closure $A'$ is connected.

What does this mean?

My professor gave use the definition of a connected set to be:

A set $\Omega$ is said to be connected if $\Omega$ is not the union of nonempty separated subsets of a metric space X.

Does this mean that $A \cap B'  = 0$ $A' \cap B  = 0$, where $A'$ and $B'$ are the closures of A and B, respectively.

Definition of separated:
Let $A$ and $B$ be two subsets of a metric space X. $A$ and $B$ are said to be separated if $A \cap B' = 0$ and $A' \cap B  = 0$

Comment: Have you made an attempt to answer the question?

Comment: When you write separated you mean disjoint right?

Comment: @lastgunslinger What is $B$?

Comment: B is a subset of a metric space X  @JosuéTonelli-Cueto and separated does not mean disjoint

Comment: This 'definition' seems more complicated than the standard definition of connectedness. i.e, $\Omega$ is connected if there does not exist disjoint open sets $U,V$ such that $U\cup V\supseteq \Omega$.

Comment: By the way your definition of separated seems wrong, the intersections should be empty. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separated_sets

Comment: It seems that the definition was incorrect, you are right @Keen-ameteur it should be empty

Comment: How could the intersection between A and the closure of B be equal to A?

Answer (score 2):

This is proven by contradiction.

Assume to the contrary that $\overline{A}=U\cup V$ where $U$ and $V$ are nonempty and separated. Show that $A\cap U$ and $A\cap V$ must also be separated in contradiction to the assumption.

This is an outline without giving the whole proof.